# Show that a function $f$ differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and such that $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(x)=0$ for any $x \ne 0$ doesn't exist

Tags: analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

> Show that a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(x)=0$ for any $x \ne 0$ doesn't exist.

My try: assume by contradiction that such function exists. Then, since it is $f'(x)=0$ for any $x>0$ and $f'(x)=0$ for any $x<0$ with $f$ differentiable and $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,\infty)$ intervals, for the mean value theorem there exist two constants $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=c_1$ for any $x>0$ and $f(x)=c_2$ for any $x<0$.

Assume $c_1\ne c_2$, then:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=c_1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=c_2$$
So $f$ is not continuous in $x=0$, but this contradicts that $f'(0)=1$ exists and so that $f$ is continuous in $x=0$ because differentiable in a point implies continuous in that point.

Assume $c_1=c_2=c$, hence:
$$1=f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c-f(0)}{h}$$
If $c=f(0)$, it is $1=f'(0)=0$ and this is a contradiction. If $c \ne f(0)$, the latter limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on the sign of $c-f(0)$ and if $h \to 0^+$ or $h \to 0^-$ but, in any possible cases, it is not finite. This contradicts that $f'(0)$ exists.

I am not sure about this proof because it seems to me that I'm not using the fact that $f'(0)$ is equal to $1$, I could replace $1$ with any other constant different from $0$. So maybe I am doing something wrong or this problem can be generalized. Can someone confirm my proof or point out its mistakes, please?

Comment: Darboux Theorem says any derivative has Intermediate Value Property. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Your proof looks workable, but may be more natural if phrased by assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$: First you show $f$ is constant on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$; then use differentiability at $0$ to deduce continuity, so "the constants are equal," i.e., $f$ is constant on $(-\infty,\infty)$, and finally deduce $f'(0) = 0$.